# Converting a list of object values to group

Tags: java, list

I have the following piece of code

```
OrderCriteria o1 = new OrderCriteria(1, 1, 101, 201);
OrderCriteria o2 = new OrderCriteria(1, 1, 102, 202);
OrderCriteria o4 = new OrderCriteria(1, 1, 102, 201);
OrderCriteria o5 = new OrderCriteria(2, 2, 501, 601);
OrderCriteria o6 = new OrderCriteria(2, 2, 501, 602);
OrderCriteria o7 = new OrderCriteria(2, 2, 502, 601);
OrderCriteria o8 = new OrderCriteria(2, 2, 502, 602);
OrderCriteria o9 = new OrderCriteria(2, 2, 503, 603);
```

Where `OrderCriteria` looks like below:

```
public class OrderCriteria {
    private final long orderId;
    private final long orderCatalogId;
    private final long procedureId;
    private final long diagnosisId;

    public OrderCriteria(long orderId, long orderCatalogId, long procedureId, long diagnosisId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.orderCatalogId = orderCatalogId;
        this.procedureId = procedureId;
        this.diagnosisId = diagnosisId;
    }

    // Getters
}
```

What I want is to get a list of procedures and list of diagnosis grouped by order id. So it should return:

```
{1, {101, 102}, {201, 202}}
{2, {501, 502, 503}, {601, 602, 603}}
```

which means Order with id 1 is having procedure ids 101, 102 and diagnosis ids 201, 202 etc. I tried using google guava table but could not come up with any valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need a new structure to hold the grouped data:

```
class OrderCriteriaGroup {
    final Set<Long> procedures = new HashSet<>();
    final Set<Long> diagnoses = new HashSet<>();

    void add(OrderCriteria o) {
        procedures.add(o.getProcedureId());
        diagnoses.add(o.getDiagnosisId());
    }

    OrderCriteriaGroup merge(OrderCriteriaGroup g) {
        procedures.addAll(g.procedures);
        diagnoses.addAll(g.diagnoses);
        return this;
    }
}
```

`add()` and `merge()` are convenience methods that will help us stream and collect the data, like so:

```
Map<Long, OrderCriteriaGroup> grouped = criteriaList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrderCriteria::getOrderId,
                Collector.of(
                        OrderCriteriaGroup::new,
                        OrderCriteriaGroup::add,
                        OrderCriteriaGroup::merge)));
```

Comment: I tried using above solution but getting compile error as The method of(Supplier<R>, BiConsumer<R,T>, BinaryOperator<R>, Collector.Characteristics...) in the type Collector is not applicable for the arguments (OrderCriteriaGroup::new, OrderCriteriaGroup::add, OrderCriteriaGroup::merge)

Comment: @StonecoldIM There was a small typo, but it works for me now: https://ideone.com/L0ihmk

Comment: Thanks a lot shmosel. God bless you Sir. Highly appreciated. It is working for me and this is going to be very helpful to continue with what I am currently doing. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to change the output structure. The current, according to your example is probably `Map<List<Set<Long>>>`. I suggest you distinguish between `"procedure:` and `"diagnosis"` set of data using the following structure:

```
Map<Long, Map<String, Set<Long>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Now filling the data is quite easy:

```
for (OrderCriteria oc: list) {
     if (map.containsKey(oc.getOrderId())) {
        map.get(oc.getOrderId()).get("procedure").add(oc.getProcedureId());
        map.get(oc.getOrderId()).get("diagnosis").add(oc.getDiagnosisId());
     } else {
        Map<String, Set<Long>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
        innerMap.put("procedure", new HashSet<>());
        innerMap.put("diagnosis", new HashSet<>());
        map.put(oc.getOrderId(), innerMap);
     }
}
```

Output: `{1={diagnosis=[201, 202], procedure=[102]}, 2={diagnosis=[601, 602, 603], procedure=[501, 502, 503]}}`

---

If you insist on the structure you have drafted, you would have to remember that the first `Set` contains procedures and the second one contains the diagnosis and the maintenaince would be impractical.

```
Map<Long, List<Set<Long>>> map = new HashMap<>();   

for (OrderCriteria oc: list) {
     if (map.containsKey(oc.getOrderId())) {    
        map.get(oc.getOrderId()).get(0).add(oc.getProcedureId());
        map.get(oc.getOrderId()).get(1).add(oc.getDiagnosisId());
     } else {
        List<Set<Long>> listOfSet = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfSet.add(new HashSet<>());
        listOfSet.add(new HashSet<>());
        map.put(oc.getOrderId(), listOfSet);
     }
}
```

Output: `{1=[[102], [201, 202]], 2=[[501, 502, 503], [601, 602, 603]]}`

---

Alternatively you might want to create a new object with 2 `Set<Long>` to store the data instead (another answer shows the way).

Comment: Very close to what I am looking for but for some reason the procedure id 101 is being filtered here.